# How to read iOS level notification settings from notification centre

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

I am using 3rd party tool for Push notification. Need help from you regarding, how to check if user send app into background and disable iOS level setting from Notification tab under iPhone setting. Is there any way to recognise, status of notification switch from setting into our app?

We wanted to display overlay inside the app, if notification are disable from settings.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8, you can use:

```
-currentUserNotificationSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isOpen = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
if (isOpen) {
    return  YES;
} else {
    return  NO;
}
```